# Visual Studio 2017 Community - HTML&CSS validation

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, razor

I am web developing (static pages / web apps) and strugling with HTML and CSS validation. Basic validation like checking closed tags ect. works fine. The issue is that how to check if typo was done in HTML code (visual studio community is a must)?

For example we have own defined CSS class:

```
.myclass {
  color: red;
}
```

And HTML code:

```
<div class ="myclas"></div>
```

In that case a typo ("myclass " vs "myclas") is not pointed by VS and I have to search it by myself.

Comment: How would VS know that it was a typo and not a separate class? I don't think any IDE could help you spot this type of error.

Comment: Nice hint but If I have CSS cources attached in project - shouldn't IDE check the availability of class used in HTML? -> if it exists in CSS somewhere and If not then shows the error. Or my thinking is wrong...I mean a similar checking when you do a typo with class/method typo mistake in backend code.

Comment: Classes aren't used only as CSS selectors. A class could be used as an identifier for a JavaScript selector. It could also be used by a third party CSS or JS library that isn't in your local project - your IDE would not know about the internals of these libraries. It would be wrong for your IDE to flag it as an error just because it isn't used in your local CSS files.